# Netbook as a cellphone?

Tags: netbook

Anyone know of a netbook that has cell phone capability?  I mean something where I can hookup a headset of some sort and make phone calls over a cellular plan with a major network like TMobile.

I want to get a smartphone, but I am also wanting to get a netbook, but it seems silly to lug both around.  It'd seem like a netbook that could make and receive cellular calls would be great, I guess the netbook would have to be on all the time though.

Comment: I just visualized a person holding a netbook up to their head like a phone :D.

Comment: Haha there is actually a video like that where a guy is walking around yelling into an IPad.  I would find it for you but I'm at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung Galaxy is the closest thing I've found to this in one package.

Answer (score 5):

Too be honest all you need is internet on your netbook and then have a service like Skype or Google Voice enabling you to make calls with it

I'm not sure if there are any netbooks with built-in 3G, but you could achieve the same effect with a dongle

Update: you could take the [Nokia Booklet 3G](http://europe.nokia.com/find-products/mini-laptops), though a dongle gives you much more freedom in what model you want

Comment: +1 since Skype/GVoice + an aircard could give me this, although this isn't as flexible or reliable as something like the Samsung Galaxy since with Skype+aircard you would be completely reliant on having a dat connection through wifi or 3g available, instead of being able to fall back on a standard voice only cell network.